# can I convert a unordered list created via for loop into treeview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

Hi！ I need to design a webpage of grocery, the webpage is devided into left-right two sides by table. 
In a.js, I read two xml files using ajax and store the values inside two arrays (categoryarray & productarray, they were created in a.js). And I use a for loop to combine two arrays and create a ordered list like below

```
i.food 
  a) product
  b) another product
ii. drink
  a) coke
  b) juice
```

on the right side I need to create a treeview of the category & product list in b.js. If so, can I repeat the for loop in b.js to create a same list, and then convert the list into treeview? Is that viable? Or there is a better way to do it? Because we are requested to use jquery to display the arrays in treeview.
Below is what I have in b.js, but it is not working at all.

```
    ;(function($) {
    for(var k=0;k<categoryarray.length;k++){
            if(categoryarray[k][0]!==""){
                $('.tree').append('<li id="Cate_' + k + '">'+categoryarray[k][1]+'</li>');
                for(var l=0;l<productarray.length;l++){
                    if(categoryarray[k][0]==productarray[l][2]){
                        $('#Cate_' + k).append('<ul id="Pro_' + l + '"></ul>');
                        $('#Pro_' + l).append("<li>"+productarray[l][1]+"</li>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

})(jQuery);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you add your code as well?

Comment: Hi Kiran, which part of codes do you want to see?

Comment: Code you have done yet.

Comment: @KiranShahi Hi Kiran! I have updated my post with b.js inside, but it is not working properly. For a.js, I simply read xml files and store them into arrays. And The arrays were defined in html file as public.

Comment: what output did you get from above code?

Comment: @KiranShahi It yields nothing at all. not even console erroe